# How to use an actioscript static member from a flex tag?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I am developping a **mobile** flex project. I created an actionscript class :

```
package
{
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    public class Config
    {
        public static var config_so:SharedObject;
        public static var db_so:SharedObject;
        public function Config()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then I set data to the sharedobject in a view :

```
Config.config_so.data.url = url.text;
Config.config_so.flush();
```

Now I want to use this sharedobject parameter data inside the parameter value of a HTTPService item : `<mx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="here_the_sharedobject_param_value/crr.php" resultFormat="text" ... />`

So how to call ( get ) the sharedobject param value inside the `url` param value of the `HTTPService` item ?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Flex data binding, like this:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="{ Config.config_so.data.url + '/crr.php'}" resultFormat="text" ... />
```

Comment: He'd also have to make the class, or at least the static var Bindable.  And I thought, for Bindable to work, the class will have to extend EventDispatcher from the Config class.  I'll also add that, according to the docs, http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html , static var will only be set once, on app load [thus they will not be updated if the static var value changes]

Comment: @Reboog711 They doesn't necessarily have to set it as bindable. If the URL is static and is available during the Flex creation life-cycle time, they can just do it as-is. Bindable is only needed if the data is going to change while the view is live. More than likely, that is not the case here. They will only get an warning saying "Object varName not bindable" in the console during debug.

Comment: @JoshJanusch You're right about not setting it to Binding; I just did a quick test.  However, I still see a lot of problems.  If the url variable is part of a SharedObject, when is that SharedObject loaded in relation to the rest of the application setup?  Will the data be loaded too late for the value to be set?  My intuition is that he cannot consistently assume that the url variable will be loaded from the shared object before the binding takes place.

Comment: @Reboog711 Fair points. Though easy enough to work around (just make sure you set it before loading that object). Then again, this could all be avoided if the property was just set in AS3 instead.

Comment: Good points @JoshJanusch and Reboog711, but please note that I just pointed how to use the variable in the URL, I didn't really go deep inside the subject. About static binding, I didn't remember that it gets assigned only once. Finally Josh is right about setting the property using pure AS3, it'd really clear things up and would be easier to use.